# How to float body right in ie

Tags: css

I am trying to give some width to body and trying to align it right to the screen using below code

```
 body{
       width : 75%;
       float : right;
 }
```

It is not working only in IE. How can I fix that..? By the default it is aligning to left.

Comment: You have a double colon maybe?

Comment: @OliMillington It was typo... I hope you have understood before also. Downvote could not help to reduce typos,..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating your body makes no sense, since it's the top op the DOM tree.  What would it float in?

If you want to give the impression that your body is only occuping the right 75% of the screen, add a margin instead.

```
body {
  margin-left: 25%;
}
```

This will work.

If this is not acceptable, use a div around your content.

Comment: Yes this is working fine for me. I was just wondering why it was not working only in IE.

Comment: it would float in the <html> element which is the top op / root element.

Comment: @Jawad some browsers will indeed allow you to see it that way; but the correct definition would say that the `html` element does not participate in the visual layout of the page.  Neither does `head`.  The visual part is completely contained in `body`.